# Build-Essential: Command Not Found on WSL

Tags: linux, windows, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am currently trying to setup my Windows 10 Dev Box with WSL. I have successfully install Ubuntu (Ubuntu 16.04.3) on a Windows 10 Insider Preview Version 1803 (OS Build 17666.1000). Using this walkthru to setup a RoR Dev ENV. [Getting Rails app to...](https://www.devmynd.com/blog/getting-rails-app-run-bash-ubuntu-windows/)

`sudo apt-get update` seems to run fine.
`sudo apt-get install git-core curl zlib1g-dev` seems to run fine except  `libfreetype6` is no longer required.

When I try to run a `build-essential` command it gives me this message: `build-essential: command not found`

I try to `apt-get autoremove` to see if the `libfreetype6` is causing the issue, no dice. I try `sudo apt-get install --reinstall build-essential` and it installs, but as soon as I run another `build-essential` command, it's not found again. Am I missing something?

Any help or direction would be awesome. Thanks.

Comment: `build-essential` is a *package*, not a *command*. Why are you trying to execute it?

Comment: Alright, that makes more sense. I broke a big command up into separate parts and that's what's causing the issue. Will correct and confirm this is the solution later this afternoon. Thanks for the feedback Biffen!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing nothing. `build-essential` is a *package*, not a *command*.

If you do `apt show build-essential`, you will notice this line:

```
Depends: libc6-dev | libc-dev, gcc (>= 4:7.2), g++ (>= 4:7.2), make, dpkg-dev (>= 1.17.11)
```

So it's just a convenient package that installs a set of essential build tools.

Furthermore, if you do `dpkg -L build-essential`, you will find that it contains nothing in `/usr/bin` (or whatever binary directory).

Answer (score -1):

you have to install `build-essential`. first update repo list and update your libs, then install it.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

Comment: @Roberto, he *did* do that ... the **problem** was that he tried to *run* the package name ...

Answer (score -1):

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

It works for me in WSL, thanks Roberto

Comment: Same answer as Roberto's which was posted before this. There was no addition to the answer. [Resource](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311662/what-to-do-with-answers-that-are-copy-and-paste-of-other-answers-here)